# SiddhiQL complex filter condition on table

Tags: siddhi

I have a table T(name string,id string) and i receive events from a stream X(name string,id string).
When i receive an event, if the name does not exist in table T, I want to insert the name and id into table and send that event to output stream. If the name exists in the table, i want to send that event to output stream only if the id against the name in the table matches to that of the id received in event.
Ex -

```
Table Data
name     |id
qwerty   |12345

Event 1 = {qwerty,123}
Event 2 = {qwerty,12345}
Event 3 = {asdf,12}
```

In the above scenario, I want to ignore event 1 , send event2 to output stream and add event3 name and id in table and then send it to output stream.

Is this possible in siddhiql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use siddhi [table joins](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#join-table) especially left outer join with name as the condition and filter out other cases along the way

1. Inner joins for case 1 and 2, This will only return event if the name and id match.

```
from XStream left outer join ATable 
  on XStream.name == ATable.name 
select Xstream.name, XStream.id, ATable.name as tableName, ATable.id as tableId 
insert into OutputStream;

from Outputstream[tableName is null] 
select name, id 
insert into ATable;

-- Here if the table name is not null it will be equal to XStream.name based on the first query
from Outputstream[not(tableName is null) and (tableId == id)] 
select name, id 
insert into FilteredStream;
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I receive two events with same name and different id simultaneously and that name does not exist in table. Won't both of them insert into table? If yes, i want only one of them to be inserted into table

Comment: If the source is not multithreaded such as Kafka, then each event is executed sequentially, you will not get this problem in the normal case. Have you tried it out? Is it the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try it out but just had a doubt and wanted to clear it.